# Regex returns empty array in php only

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex to filter all Links that contain "Kontakt" or "Contact" as Text.

`<a.*href=["|\'](.*?)["|\'].*>.*[k|K|c|C]onta[k|c]t[^>]*\s*?<\/a>`

Testing it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZMqHsn/2) it works as expected, but when I implement it in my PHP, it gives me an empty array:

`preg_match('/<a.*href=["|\'](.*?)["|\'].*>.*[k|K|c|C]onta[k|c]t[^>]*?<\/a>/', $html, $matches);`

`var_dump($matches);` returns `array(0) {}` where am I missing something?

This probably is not the most elegant way to find texts like `Kontakt`, `contact` or `Click here for our contact-details` and I am open to improvements, but this may not be the issue here?

Comment: A character class `[]` is already a list of characters. The `|` is not needed, and allows for literal `|`s. The generated PHP code from your regex works. https://3v4l.org/hLsJI your version also works, https://3v4l.org/jXWkv I'd guess `$html` has something other than what you expect

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML

Comment: Make sure to make all your `.*` non-greedy by adding a `?` and to use `preg_match_all` to mimic the `g` modifier which you used on regex101: [demo](https://3v4l.org/cp4Dq). Still, it is bad practice to use regex for parsing HTML, so walk away from it and use the `DomDocument` interface.